# How to use couchdb properly to chain mapreduce functions or group properly

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, couchdb

I'd like to reduce the amount of data I have and preprocess it before I return it to only populate the calculated data.
As a simply Example I have following series of data, representing a value at a given time in hours:minutes

```
var testdata = [ //
    {_id: '01', timestamp: [01, 10], value: 100},
    {_id: '02', timestamp: [01, 20], value: 101},
    {_id: '03', timestamp: [01, 30], value: 102},
    {_id: '04', timestamp: [02, 10], value: 103},
    {_id: '05', timestamp: [02, 20], value: 104},
    {_id: '06', timestamp: [02, 30], value: 105},
    {_id: '07', timestamp: [03, 10], value: 106},
    {_id: '08', timestamp: [03, 20], value: 107},
    {_id: '09', timestamp: [03, 30], value: 108},
    {_id: '10', timestamp: [03, 40], value: 109},
    {_id: '11', timestamp: [04, 10], value: 110},
    {_id: '12', timestamp: [04, 20], value: 111}
];
```

So on the lowest grouping I'd like to have the detla of the values, meaning:

```
key: 01 value: 100; // 100 - 0 = 100
key: 02 value: 1; // 101-100=1
key: 03 value: 1; // 102-101=1
key: 04 value: 1; // 103-102=1
key: 05 value: 1; // 104-103=1
key: 06 value: 1; //...
key: 07 value: 1; //...
key: 08 value: 1; //...
key: 09 value: 1; //...
key: 10 value: 1; //...
key: 11 value: 1; //...
key: 12 value: 1; //...
```

I already have no clue how to achieve this in couchdb. As there is no deeper cascading of data, there is nothing to group and therefore "reduce".

The next step would be to group on hours, meaning, aggregating the results from before

```
key: 01 value: 102; // 100+1+1=102
key: 02 value: 3; // 1+1+1=3
key: 03 value: 4; // 1+1+1+1=4
key: 04 value: 2; // 1+1=2
```

Finally the result of a whole day would be

```
key : 01, value: 111;
```

So my question is, is it actually possible to do this kind of task within couchdb, or should I simply return the absolute values and perform my calculations on the client side to display a chart?

Answer (score 1):

I’m not sure it’s impossible using reduce, but it seems at least hard.

In fact you can do it without reduce – use `_list` function instead. Unlike reduce, list fns receive entire view result in exact order – so you always know where your data chunk starts and how long it is.

Another benefit is that you can perform all your fold cycles in one API request and send all folds as a single object – unlike map/reduce, `_list` fns can send result of any structure (and any mime).

See http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/api/ddoc/render.html#db-design-design-doc-list-list-name-view-name for more info.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you cannot get the delta values in the Map/Reduce paradigm. The reason is that any two key/value pairs might not be matched up in the reduce phase, and outside the reduce phase you can only work with a single document.

On the other hand, cascading from minutes to hours and so on should work fine, but that's probably not enough for you.